# How can I add Datepicker in DjangoCreateView

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms, django-widget

```
#view.py
class JobCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Job
    template_name = 'Job_create.html'
    fields = ['Company' ,'Job_title','Department','Start_date','end_date','Consent']

    def form_valid(self, form):
       form.instance.Alumni_id = self.request.user.alumni
       return super().form_valid(form)

    def get_form(self):
      '''add date picker in forms'''      
       form = super(JobCreateView, self).get_form()
       form.fields['end_date'].widget = forms.SelectDateWidget()
       return form
```

from `get_form` function I got [this kind of date Input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jKSeA.png) but I want a date picker that's look like a calender

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by a date picker that looks like a calendar?

Answer (score 0):

I think this should fix it. It would use the native [date picker in HTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date).

```py
form.fields['end_date'].widget = forms.DateInput(attrs={'type': 'date'})
```